# How can I stop C++ recv() when string read is finished?

Tags: c++, sockets, recv

I am reading an Image URL sent from a Java client to a C++ server from Sockets. The server stops reading through recv() when it detects there is a null character in the char buffer[] as I do below in the following code:

```
void * SocketServer::clientController(void *obj)
{
    // Retrieve client connection information
    dataSocket *data = (dataSocket*) obj;

    // Receive data from a client step by step and append data in String message
    string message;
    int bytes = 0;
    do
    {
        char buffer[12] = {0};
        bytes = recv(data->descriptor, buffer, 12, 0);

        if (bytes > 0) // Build message
        {
            message.append(buffer, bytes);
            cout << "Message: " << message << endl;
        }
        else // Error when receiving it
            cout << "Error receiving image URL" << endl;


        // Check if we are finished reading the image link
        unsigned int i = 0;
        bool finished = false;
        while (i < sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]) && !finished)
        {
            finished = buffer[i] == '\0';
            i++;
        }

        if (finished)
            break;

    }
    while (bytes > 0);

    cout << message << endl;

    close(data->descriptor);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

***Is there a better and more elegant way to make this?***

I read about sending first the size of the URL, but I do not know exactly how to stop recv() with it. I guess it is done by counting the bytes received until the size of the URL is reached. At that moment, we should be finished reading.

Another approach could be closing the Java socket so that recv() will return -1 and the loop will be finished. However, considering my Java client waits for a response from C++ server, closing the socket and then reopen it does not seem a suitable option.

Thank you,
Héctor

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that your buffer has an unusual size (one typically chooses a power of 2, so 8, 16, 32, ...) and it looks a little small for your intent, your approach seems fine to me:

I assume that your java client will send a null terminated string and then wait anyway, i. e. especially it does not send any further data. So after you received the 0 character, there won't be any data to receive any more anyway, so there is not need to bother for something explicitly that recv does implicitly ([recv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) normally returns only the data available, even if less than the buffer could consume).

Be aware that you initialized buffer with 0, so if you check the entire buffer (instead of the range [`buffer, buffer + bytes`), you might detect a false positive (if you receive less than 12 characters in the first iteration)! Detection of the 0 character can be done more elegantly, though, anyway:

```
if(std::find(buffer, buffer + bytes, 0) < buffer + bytes)
{
    // found the 0 character!
    break;
}
```